# swift touchesBegan and show it on the touched object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I want show the x corrdinate of a touched and moved object.

Try it out:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)        
    @IBOutlet weak var viewBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cntInViewBox: UILabel!

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        viewBox.center = location
        /*cntInViewBox.text=String(location.x)*/
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        viewBox.center = location          
        /*cntInViewBox.text=String(location.x)*/
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewBox.center = CGPoint(x:0, y: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

}

Without the Line

```
cntIntViewBox.text=String(location.x)
```

it works great. Touching on the sceen, the viewBox jumps, starting Touching, the box is moving.

But if I activate the line to show the coordinate (for example, I mean any dynamic text), moving and jumping is not working anymore.

why does this issue arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your line changes the text of a label. This causes Auto Layout to be performed throughout your interface. Your `viewBox` view is positioned by Auto Layout constraints, so those constraints take over and are used to position the view. The constraints didn't change so the view doesn't move.

Comment: Wow...perfect answer. I fully understand it. Any solution: Can I deactive Auto layouting programmatically?

Comment: You really don't need to do that. Instead of changing the view's `center`, you can change its constraints. However, if you really want to remove this one view from auto layout entirely, you can; the simplest way is to create the view in code instead of in the storyboard.